# Added nested object attribute through nested map

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to assign a new nested attribute called `likeTotalForComment` like this:

```
{
     comment: [
          {
               likeTotalForComment:
          }
     ]
}
```

This is what I currently have written:

```
commentLikes = data.map(
                    (v,i) => {

                  return(  v.comment.map(
                            (c, ci) => {
                              newValue = sumFunc(data[i].comment[ci].like, 'value')
                              return data[i].comment[ci] = {likeTotalForComment: newValue}
                            }
                        )

                      )
                    }
                )

console.log(commentLikes)
```

The return gives me this

```
[[{likeTotalForComment: 2}, {likeTotalForComment: 4}]]
```

Not the entire object with a new nested attribute, which is what I want

Here is some sample data: https://codepen.io/schoenbl/pen/gVgJLm?editors=0010

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Object.spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the new attribute to the old object

```
data = data.map(v => {
  return {...v, comment: v.comment.map(c => {
    let newValue = sumFunc(c.like, 'value');
    return { ...c, likeTotalForComment: newValue };
  })}
});
```

or just assign a new property to the old object

```
data.forEach(v => {
  data.comment.forEach((comment) => {
    let newValue = sumFunc(c.like, 'value');
    comment['likeTotalForComment'] = newValue
  });
})
```